# Connecting an Arduino oled display without a breadboard

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, wiring, display, oled

I am new to Arduino and over all electrical and computer engineering. I need some help with connecting an OLED display to my Arduino. The problem is, I do not currently have a breadboard. If I need a breadboard that is fine, but I would prefer to go without it. I would also prefer to go without soldering it to the board, as this is a temporary project.

I need to connect the display to the VCC, GND, SCL, and SDA pins and ports.

I have an Arduino Uno R3.

Here's a link to the the display on Amazon (hopefully this is needed info.)
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00O2LLT30/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O2LLT30)

Here's a picture of the display itself.

[image: The display I am using]

Comment: Short, mini grabber/hook jumper wires (test clips) may do the job... e.g. Google "Pomona minigrabber"

Comment: The display has pins, and Uno has header sockets and they should be kept short or twisted  to reduce EMI ingress.  These are accept standard square pins used in headers and some round pins.

Comment: Quick little comment, in the display photo it shows wires, those do not actually come with the display.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very easy task, since this OLED display have only 4 wires.

You'll need wires like these:

[image: JUMPERS]

You can find them easily, search for "dupont wire" or "dupont jumpers". Maybe you'll need to solder one end of the wire to the display. Theses wires are in a ribbon, but you can strip them as needed.

Connect Arduino's GND to display's GND; 
    (usually this connection uses black wire)

Connect Arduino's 3.3v to display's VCC;
    (usually this connection uses orange wire)

Connect Arduino's A5 to displays's SCL;
Connect Arduino's A4 to displays's SDA;

You can connect the display's SCL and SDA to other arduino's pins, but you'll need to adjust the sketch to the pins that you've used.

Answer (score 1):

what you need are female-female dupont jumper wires. (female means a hole for a pin, male would be a pin to stick into a hole. i know, haha, but its the official terminology) anyway, try [these](https://www.ebay.com/itm/40pcs-10cm-Female-To-Female-Dupont-Wire-Jumper-Cable-for-Arduino-Breadboard/201943176553?epid=1366226110). when you get them, they come all connected together, but you can peel individual ones off and use them individually.